# running php on mamp

Tags: php, mamp

I already installed MAMP in my macbook pro. I want to run a php. what can i do?

Comment: The P in MAMP is PHP. If MAMP is running, PHP is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have done everything right, open your browser and type this:

```
http://localhost
```

to see if it opens successfully and then you can open your sites.

Also check out the mamp's documentation on how to configure it and run php scripts.

Answer (score 31):

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hello.php

Will then appear in http://localhost:8888/hello.php

:)

Comment: sometime it is not "8888" - take a look at the mamp settings > Ports > Apache-Port

Comment: Awesome answer!!

Answer (score 5):

Drop the PHP file into the HTDOCs folder in MAMP, for example let's call it  hello_world.php  and now you can run it by going to:

http://localhost/hello_world.php

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the port settings of MAMP (Preferences -> Ports) you have to call `http://localhost:8888/filename.php` (MAMP ports) or `http://localhost/filename.php` (default ports). The file "filename.php" have to be located in this folder: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/