# PHP not working on MAMP?

Tags: php, mamp

I'm new to this so please forgive me.

I have set up MAMP and am trying to run a PHP file (index.php). I have the green lights and have my index.php file inside the htdocs folder.

But nothing seems to show up in the browser.

Here is my setup[image]

I have done as told in the answers in this question [running php on mamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283456/running-php-on-mamp)

which includes:

```
http://localhost/index.php
http://localhost:8888/index.php
```

both give me a bank page.

I tried /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php and it give me this.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
<php? echo"hello"; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

---

The php's tags are:

`<?php` for opening and `?>` for closing

[Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: @MichaelSórm: There are ways to find these errors. You can enable error reporting in PHP, or just look in your Apache logs to find out what's wrong.

Comment: @MichaelSórm Everyone has the first time, don't worry :)

Comment: @elclanrs: error_reporting() is useful but I think in this case '<php? ' , it would not work...

Comment: I agree with @Aaron Gong. The reason it didn't work is that the PHP pre-processor did not recognize the block as PHP code and instead recognized it as plain text so it would have no reason to throw an error. If you throw this into the W3C HTML Validator using an XHTML strict doctype it still doesn't even cause so much as a warning. If you use a HTML 5 doctype it does throw an error though.

Comment: I agree too, error reporting in this case is not usefull, but is good that he mentioned for the future develop